# Why is the reward signal normalized in openAI's REINFORCE?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, reward-normalization

[Pytorch's example for the REINFORCE algorithm](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/reinforcement_learning/reinforce.py) for reinforcement learning has the following code:

```
import argparse
import gym
import numpy as np
from itertools import count

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.distributions import Categorical


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='PyTorch REINFORCE example')
parser.add_argument('--gamma', type=float, default=0.99, metavar='G',
                    help='discount factor (default: 0.99)')
parser.add_argument('--seed', type=int, default=543, metavar='N',
                    help='random seed (default: 543)')
parser.add_argument('--render', action='store_true',
                    help='render the environment')
parser.add_argument('--log-interval', type=int, default=10, metavar='N',
                    help='interval between training status logs (default: 10)')
args = parser.parse_args()


env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
env.seed(args.seed)
torch.manual_seed(args.seed)


class Policy(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Policy, self).__init__()
        self.affine1 = nn.Linear(4, 128)
        self.affine2 = nn.Linear(128, 2)

        self.saved_log_probs = []
        self.rewards = []

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.affine1(x))
        action_scores = self.affine2(x)
        return F.softmax(action_scores, dim=1)


policy = Policy()
optimizer = optim.Adam(policy.parameters(), lr=1e-2)
eps = np.finfo(np.float32).eps.item()


def select_action(state):
    state = torch.from_numpy(state).float().unsqueeze(0)
    probs = policy(state)
    m = Categorical(probs)
    action = m.sample()
    policy.saved_log_probs.append(m.log_prob(action))
    return action.item()


def finish_episode():
    R = 0
    policy_loss = []
    rewards = []
    for r in policy.rewards[::-1]:
        R = r + args.gamma * R
        rewards.insert(0, R)
    rewards = torch.tensor(rewards)
    rewards = (rewards - rewards.mean()) / (rewards.std() + eps)
    for log_prob, reward in zip(policy.saved_log_probs, rewards):
        policy_loss.append(-log_prob * reward)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    policy_loss = torch.cat(policy_loss).sum()
    policy_loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    del policy.rewards[:]
    del policy.saved_log_probs[:]


def main():
    running_reward = 10
    for i_episode in count(1):
        state = env.reset()
        for t in range(10000):  # Don't infinite loop while learning
            action = select_action(state)
            state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
            if args.render:
                env.render()
            policy.rewards.append(reward)
            if done:
                break

        running_reward = running_reward * 0.99 + t * 0.01
        finish_episode()
        if i_episode % args.log_interval == 0:
            print('Episode {}\tLast length: {:5d}\tAverage length: {:.2f}'.format(
                i_episode, t, running_reward))
        if running_reward > env.spec.reward_threshold:
            print("Solved! Running reward is now {} and "
                  "the last episode runs to {} time steps!".format(running_reward, t))
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

I am interested in the function `finish_episode()`:

the line

```
 rewards = (rewards - rewards.mean()) / (rewards.std() + eps)
```

makes no sense to me.

I thought this might be [baseline reduction](https://www.quora.com/Why-can-reinforcement-of-the-baseline-reduce-variance), but I can't see why divide by the standard deviation.

If it isn't baseline reduction, then why normalize the rewards, and where should the baseline reduction go?

Please explain that line

Answer (score 3):

It's just a hack to normalize the rewards to make optimization less problematic in cases where the reward might have very large/small values. It's fine because scaling the rewards by a constant factor won't change what the optimal policy is. You can think of the mean reward as the baseline.

Comment: The mean reward is the baseline, i get it, but why divide by the standard deviation?

Comment: Also, that constant does change between episodes. Could you please elaborate on how that actually works?